# IguanaTex doesn't access the LaTeX process

Tags: errors, miktex, windows

I run [IguanaTex](http://www.technion.ac.il/~zvikabh/software/iguanatex/) 32-bit in Office 2010 32-bit / Windows 7 SP1 64x with MikTeX 2.9 32-bit. When I try to compile some TeX things with IguanaTeX to PPT, I get the error `"Could not start process 'latex -interaction=batchmode "addin_tmp.tex"' GetLastError returned 0"`.

The prompt `latex -interaction=batchmode "addin_tmp.tex"` runs properly on PowerShell 32-bit and 64-bit and on `cmd.exe` (both in C:\Temp).

I already tried to repair and reinstall IguanaTeX and to run PPT with admin rights.

Comment: Hi Hartmut to TeX.SE. This is a strange error, as mentioned in the IguanaTex FAQ this should only happen if Iguana cannot find the Miktex installation. I have exactly the same setup running nicely here. Did you run Powerpoint and cmd.exe as the same user?

Comment: Yes, I ran it as the same user. (Tech specs: HP Pavillion p6 2023de; AMD A8 APU; 8GB RAM; NVidia GT545)

Comment: Sorry, then I have few ideas. IguanaTex uses a VBA function to call `latex`, maybe some security setting/virus scanner forbids the execution of the CreateProcess function. Other than that maybe try using TeXPoint. It's not free but has a 30 day trial and has the same requirements for the underlying LaTeX installation.

Comment: TeXPoint makes PPT crash on start-up. Sorry

Comment: I checked it in Norton (360 Online 6). It should be executable.

Comment: IguanaTeX also requires some packages that maybe are not installed on your system. Try with the `debug` setting on. Maybe IguanaTeX is not able to launch the MikTeX package manager for some reason.

Comment: When I turn error on, I get an alertbox with `latex -interaction=batchmode "addin_tmp.tex"` and the usual error. Then, I get a window with a log file from the successful compilation that I made through the PowerShell with the heading `Your latex code contains errors and no output was generated. The following log file contains further details`